# Determining Linear independence of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have seen that there are some examples already there on linear independence but still I have a doubt. Most of the examples have shown that for checking the linear independence of a set of vectors, DETERMINANT test can be used but this test can only be used for square matrices. What if we have a non-square matrix. For that we can use Gaussian-Elimination method. I am trying to use this method here for the following matrix.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 2 & -1 & 4 \\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
        -2 & -2 & 3 &-1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and get this Echelon Matrix

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
        0 & 2 & -7 & -5 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I get the following equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
a+2c+3d=0 \\ 
2b-7c-5d=0 \\ 
0a+0b+0c+0d=0 
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

Now I am not able to understand third equation.

Also are the vectors linearly dependent or independent. Kindly Explain. Thanks.

EDIT:

I know that the vectors are linearly independent if a=b=c=d=0 (trivial solution) and if atleast one of them is non-zero, the vectors are linearly dependent. Does the third equation states that all variables, a,b,c and d are FREE variables and can have any value(may be non-zero or zero) based on which we can say that there is no unique solution and therefore vectors are linearly dependent. Am I interpreting it right?

Comment: Which vectors are you asking about?

Comment: I assume you're talking about linear independence of the _columns_ of the matrix.

Comment: @Arthur yes you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are linearly dependent: this requires no work as there are four of them and they have height 3.

The rows are linearly dependent: this is what you have proved by Gaussian
elimination with your row of zeros. The three rows are linear combinations of
the two vectors $(1,0,2,3)$ and $(0,2,-7,-5)$, so the rows are linearly
dependent.

When solving linear equations by Gaussian elimination, if you get
an all zero row it means that one of the original equations was redundant (a consequence of the others).

Comment: I am not able to understand the first point "The columns are linearly dependent: this requires no work as there are four of them and they have height 3." Kindly elaborate. Also please see I have made an EDIT, kindly let me know, Am I interpreted it right? Thanks.

Comment: If you have more than $n$ vectors in a vector space of dimension $n$ they must be linearly dependent. In your system of equations you can pick any values you like for $c$ and $d$; then you can find $b$ and $a$ satisfying your equations. This gives an explicit linear dependence between the columns. However it was always apparent that the columns **must** have been linearly dependent.

Comment: I got you. Thank you for such a fine explanation. One last question. Are only _**c**_ and _**d**_ , the only **FREE** variables?

Comment: @Navdeep your method expresses $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$ and $d$. You could have done things the other way round and expressed $c$ and $d$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ etc.